# Google map bind on page load with db values

Tags: google-maps

I am trying to bind a Google map in an iFrame (on page load) with database values:

```
<iframe id="myMap" runat="server" width="291" height="241" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src=""></iframe><br /><small><a href="https://maps.google.co.in/?ie=UTF8&amp;t=m&amp;ll=21.125498,81.914063&amp;spn=14.315343,18.676758&amp;z=5&amp;source=embed" style="color:#0000FF;text-align:left">View Larger Map</a><br />
```

I am using the below code, but all I get in the iFrame is a blank box:

```
public void GetMapDetails(int Propertyid){
    DataSet dstPropMap = Tbl_PropertyMaster.GetPropertyDetailsbyId(Propertyid);
    if (dstPropMap.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        lat = dstPropMap.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Latitude"].ToString();
        lon = dstPropMap.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Longitude"].ToString();
        myMap.Attributes.Add("src", "https://maps.google.co.in/?ie=UTF8&amp;t=m&amp;ll=" + lat + "," + lon + "&amp;spn=" + lat + "," + lon + "amp;z=5&amp;output=embed");
        DataBind();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I Resolved this,
For some reason **adding Attributes to IFrame using Attributes.Add doesnt work**, So I switched to html **IMG** image,and put runat="server" tag to it.

**ie**

```
<img id="myMap" runat="server" width="291" height="241"/>
```

**and at code behind added Attributes.Add to IMG**

```
public void GetMapDetails(int Propertyid)
{
    DataSet dstPropMap = Tbl_PropertyMaster.GetPropertyDetailsbyId(Propertyid);
    if (dstPropMap.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        lat = dstPropMap.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Latitude"].ToString().Trim();
        lon = dstPropMap.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Longitude"].ToString().Trim();
        myMap.Attributes.Add("src", "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=" + lat + "," + lon + "&zoom=11&size=291x241&sensor=true");
    }
}
```